# Time-series database with rethinkdb

Tags: time-series, rethinkdb

I'm currently evaluating rethinkdb to use it with a time-series database for my charting needs.

I'm looking for existing tutorials and snippets if they even exist for rethinkdb. (I already know that mongodb, redis, tempodb and cassandra has similar resources).

Comment: There is a range of time-series databases available including open-source ones. I'm curious what's driving your requirements to implement your own database?

Answer (score 2):

You have some ressources on RethinkDB website:

General introduction to the query language -- http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/introduction-to-reql/
Cookbook (probably what you are looking for) -- http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/cookbook/javascript/
API docs (there are some useful examples there) -- http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/

There are some ffull apps too -- http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/examples/

I am not aware of specific snippet for time series though.
But you just have to create an index on your time serie data, and use `orderBy({index: "time"})` (something like that).